# Client-Client chatting via Microsoft Bot framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, botframework

I'm new with Microsoft Bot Framework, I'm going to build a project which my customers can chat with the bot to get information, and furthermore, I want my Bot to suggest my users whether they want to chat with the Bot or with my secrectary who uses my management website to receive customer's message forwarded by the Bot . So my question here is, how can my secretary can join the chat with customer and the Bot will keep silent. Is there anyway to do without using Conversation Chat group because my secretary may not use the Bot Framework chat control to connect. I'm thinking of using SignalR which will help my secretary chat with customers

Here is my plan:
[image: Project architect]

Comment: I apologized for my poor information, all people interact with my bot will using WebChat control that Bot Framework provides us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look to the [Bot HandOff sample](https://github.com/palindromed/Bot-HandOff) (node.js) and the [Intermediator Bot sample](https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample) (C#) as they will give you the basics to build what you are looking for.

Basically, in the samples you will see how to handoff the conversation the user is having with the bot to a human (in this case your secretary). The only pre-req is that your secretary would have to be in one of the supported channels for BotFramework, e.g. Skype and have the Bot as a contact, because the conversation between the user and the secretary would be through the bot (the bot will act as a message router).

If you use a custom channel (like your website); you still can follow some of the patterns explained in the samples.

Comment: @user1892538 well, that's mean the bot is the router as his answer. It just  responsible to forwards my customers message and my Agent message.

Comment: @Justin Van I meant, as suggested by the documentation, that you have to design the handover scenario. It could be based on [sentiment analysis](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/text-analytics-api) or simply a request of help by the user.

Comment: @user1892538 I think we don't have to use sentiment analysis, we can just use Dialog to provide "customers" to choose whether they want to chat with the bot or with the Agent. It is easier to do than sentiment analysis. But anyway, it's a good idea to make your bot smarter.

Comment: hello, i need agent similar to https://github.com/billba/agent in c#, any help please. the above agent is in node.js