# Create Multiple chat control in one website Bot Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, botframework

I want to build a project which is similar to the post I attach below. However, assume that if the secrectary must communicate with many customers at the same time.

**How can we create the number of chat controls adequate with the number of customers want to chat directly with the secrectary?**

And can we just use the chat control that Bot Framework provide us without using DirectLine API?

My previous post: [Client-client chatting via Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42442284/client-client-chatting-via-microsoft-bot-framework/42442484#42442484)

Comment: You can put many <iframe /> on the page, and each bot on one of those iframes

Comment: The circumstance here is that you don't know exactly how many </iframe? that you have to create because you don't know how many customer are there at the same time want to chat with the secrectary. Is there any way to add it dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two options:

1) you can create dynamic iframe per user and set up the user name and the id of the user and send this in the iframe :

"https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/smilesbot?s=secret_code&username=admin&userid=1234'>"

2) use the direct line on the basis of the web Chat : [webChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat)

Comment: as i've seen your first option, can we generate iframe by return it in the Message Controller ?

Comment: why do such a thing?  why not set new user name and user id in your website for each customer and add this to the iframe? Then all of a customer is defined as a one monovalent and the microsoft framework does the rest

Comment: it seems we can only set user id and user name internally.  I've tried to set it in the src of iframe but nothing happen